# Как изменить значение в Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Как изменить значение child-a в firebase?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public void updateDate(final Long oldDate, final Long newDate) {

        myRef = fbDatabase.getReference(getUid());
        myRef.keepSynced(true);
        myRef.child(TABLE_OPERATIONS)
                .orderByChild(COLUMN_DATE)
                .equalTo(oldDate)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            CategoryList post = postSnapshot.getValue(CategoryList.class);
                            if (post.getDate() == oldDate) {
                                postSnapshot.getRef().child(COLUMN_DATE).setValue(newDate);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если транзакцией, то так:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference(uid)
        .child("operations")
        .child(uidFromPush)
        .child("date")
        .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                //вот значение поля "datee"
                Longp = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                if (p == null) {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                //присваиваем новое значение, например текущее время
                p = System.cureentTimeMillis();

                // Set value and report transaction success
                mutableData.setValue(p);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (databaseError == null) {
                    //всё ОК
                } else {
                    //произошла ошибка. Она тут: databaseError.toException()
                }
            }
        });
```

Либо так, не транзакцией:

```
Map<String, Object> data= new HashMap<>();
data.put("date", System.currentTimeMissil());

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference(uid)
        .child("operations")
        .child(uidFromPush);

reference.updateChildren(data, (databaseError, databaseReference) -> {
    if (databaseError == null) {
        //всё ОК
    } else {
        //произошла ошибка. Она тут: databaseError.toException()
    }
});
```

Comment: а как получить `uidFromPush` это?

Comment: @java, когда вы делали `push` то это значение вернулось вам.

Comment: не совсем понял вас, это значение где-то хранится у меня?

Comment: Вы где-то делали что-то типа `reference.push().setValue(dataModelInstance)`. Ваш uid - результат вызова `push()`. Т.е. `DatabaseReference ref = reference.push(); String uid = ref.getKey(); ref.setValue(dataModelInstance);` Но у вас может быть совсем другая логика записи данных и да, этого UID таким образом может быть невозможно получить. В этом случае вам надо заменять логику/ вытаскивать uid другим способом, из самого firebase

Comment: я делал так `        myRef = fbDatabase.getReference(getUid());

        myRef.child(TABLE_OPERATIONS).push().setValue(test).addOnCompleteListener(listener);`

Comment: @java, перечитайте ещё раз мой коммент. Там я показал как получить uid в процессе `push`

Comment: я так и делал как вы написали в коменте, но не работает, новое значение добавляется не в нужное место, а просто создает нового child-a

Comment: @java, покажите код в вопросе

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста я добавил свой метод, он щас работает, но это плохой способ или нет?

Comment: @java, сложно что-то определённое сказать - надо знать что вы делаете зачем и как. Если цель - замена заранее известной никем не изменяемой даты - то можно и так. Если дата заранее не известна и может меняться другими клиентами и всё такое - то этот код приведёт к множеству не отлаиваемых ошибок и проблем.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое